# Mini cake with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make buttons that look like a small cake

How do I insert the top of the cake?

example:

http://oi63.tinypic.com/4tx5xj.jpg

```css
ul#menutop {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 50px 20px 20px 10px;

}

ul#menutop li {
    display: inline;

}

ul#menutop li a {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 font-size:25px;
    background-color: blue;
}

ul#menutop li a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menutop">
   <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to create additional markup, you could always use [pseudo-elements](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp).

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pxy1ya5s/)**

**[YOUR CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/bwdx2qcb/)**

```css
ul#menutop {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 50px 20px 20px 10px;

}

ul#menutop li {
    display: inline;

}

ul#menutop li a {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 font-size:25px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

ul#menutop li a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

ul#menutop li a:after {
  background: red;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0 / 5px 5px 0 0;
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul id="menutop">
   <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I were you OP, I'd go with this answer, very good and without the hassle  of extra markup as @Quoid said.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a span to each `li` item in your html:

```
<ul id="menutop">
<li> <span></span> <a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li> <span></span> <a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li> <span></span><a href="">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

And add this to your css

```
ul#menutop li span {
  background:blue;
  padding:10px;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-right:20px;
  margin-left:20px;
  height:10px;
  margin-top:-20px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/youh73bn/) a fiddle so you can play around with it, hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like following way using before.

```
ul#menutop li a::before {
    background-color: blue;
    content: "";
    height: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
    width: 50px;
}
```

And `position:relative` to `li`

```
ul#menutop li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;

}
```

Full code here:

```css
ul#menutop {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 50px 20px 20px 10px;

}

ul#menutop li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;

}

ul#menutop li a {
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
 font-size:25px;
    background-color: blue;
}
ul#menutop li a::before {
    background-color: blue;
    content: "";
    height: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
    width: 50px;
}

ul#menutop li a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

ul#menutop li a:hover:before{
   background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menutop">
   <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hjh7mq1/2/)**